# How can I define the environment when restarting a Rails app from the command line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I define the environment when restarting a Rails app from the command line?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

if you meant how to tell rails which environment to load when you start the server from command line, here's how:

```
rails server -e production
```

Comment: That works too.  The nice thing about using the shell variable though, is that it works with some kinds of commands that `-e` cannot be used with.

Comment: I prefer this method over setting RAILS_ENV since I tend to forget I have the env set to production. Most of the time I want to be running in development anyway.

Comment: The problem I had was major stupidity; i was using RAILS_ENV and wanted to print some text only in development environment. Instead writing 'if RAILS_ENV == "development"' i wrote 'if RAILS_ENV = "development" and had actually caused production environment to run as development! I'm a dumbass. Thanks for your help here.

Comment: is it possible to do the same but pass any other environment variable instead of setting  it statically in *.rb file?

Answer (score 10):

In general, Rails gets its environment from the RAILS_ENV shell variable at start-up, or defaults to "development".  You can specify an environment for a rails command such as `rails server`, `rails console` (Rails 3), `script/server` or `script/console` (Rails 2.x) from the bash command line as follows...

```
RAILS_ENV=something rails s
```

This means to set the `RAILS_ENV` environment variable to "something" for the execution of the `rails s` command.